# How to orchestrate a varying set of Docker containers on demand?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, docker-swarm, orchestration

I am pretty familiar with Docker itself, but now facing a question of how to orchestrate a varying set of Docker containers on demand for a system architecture that I am developing. I have heard of Kubernetes and Docker Swarm, but am not sure which orchestration tool would be best suited for the requirements.

**Here's the situation, what I am imagining my software architecture to work like:**

- There's 1 to N clients and 1 to M servers (probably only 1 server in the beginning).
- The clients are running 1 to X Docker containers that also communicate with each other. The Docker containers do not necessarily run the same Docker image.
- The clients can request to run a particular function on one of the servers.
- In that case, one (or more) servers are spinning up 1 to Y new Docker containers on demand. At the same time, the client is pausing/shutting down 1 or more of the X containers on the client.
- Multiple sets of different Docker containers and their server replacements could be allowed. So e.g. containers x1, x2 on the client could be substituted by containers y1, y2, y3 on the server.
- The exact configuration of which 1 to Y containers to launch on-demand and how they are connected would depend on the request made to the server.
- Given the need for a particular container y1 on the server side, it could also help to dynamically scale this container to M servers to serve more clients.

**I believe one of the core questions is:** How can I spin up 1 to X (pre-defined, but configurable) Docker containers on-demand, i.e., given some external condition? The request would be triggered by some kind of call from client to server.

I hope that I was able to understandably present my current thoughts and that they make sense. Feel free to point me to any existing tools, workflows, or even completely alternate system designs. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question is probably going to get closed as either opinion based or needs more focus: you're asking a broad question for which there is no single correct answer. If you were to pick a technology (say, Kubernetes) and try to implement a solution, we would be able to help you if you have specific technical questions about your attempts.

Comment: As @larsks said, if it helps you make a decision, we are running docker swarm (we were discussing K8s vs docker swarm, even before Mirantis took over, and we decided on docker swarm in the end). We are currently running 38 stacks each containing 2-8 services on 3 manager and 3 worker nodes. Managers are 4C16GB workers are 8c32gb. For UI / Basic administration we are using Portainer, which helps a lot. And for routing (API GW-like functionalities) we are running Traefik. For the automatic SW updates, we are using gitlab's CI system to build images from source and then deploy based on CD config.

Comment: But in the end, you need to know it ALL depends on your use case, your system requirements and how "large" your deployments and configuration will be. For us (we are mainly developing MES & ERP systems for a big manufacturing company) Docker Swarm ticked all the boxes without bringing in the complexity of the k8s. BUT I need to say we have a limitation from the given company that EVERYTHING needs to run on-prem. No clouds no hosted services nothing. All we have is run on-prem. So that was a BIG factor in k8s vs Docker Swarm as well. You need to get straight with yourself and document requireme

Comment: My experience has been that starting and stopping containers is a little bit fragile, a little bit expensive, and orchestrator-specific.  Starting a dedicated container per user or per task is slow and hits scaling limits sooner than you might like.  So if you can rearchitect this setup so that you have a shared pool of containers across all end users, and use something like a Kubernetes HorizontalPodAutoscaler to create them in response to load, your application will be somewhat simpler.